# Track AWS EC2 Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I'm looking for a way to track (via SNS notification) when someone in my organization launches a new EC2 instance. I'm currently using CloudWatch rules to track S3 bucket creation and EC2 termination. The issue with this method is that it is tracking EC2 state changes. E.g. I have multiple existing EC2 instances that will switch between **STOPPED**, **PENDING**, and **RUNNING** state. TERMINATED makes sense to track this way since it can only occur once. But is there a method I can use to get a notification only when a new instance is launched, not every time an existing instance is changed state to PENDING or RUNNING?

Comment: In thase scenario I would make the cloudwatch rule track every instance stage change and trigger a lambda function to compare the instances previous state and trigger an alarm if there is not previous state for that instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To track EC2 instance launches (as well as terminations and bucket creations), I would use [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html). You should configure this to track events cross-region and (if you're using an AWS Organization) cross-account.

There are two ways to translate CloudTrail events into SNS notifications: [CloudWatch Logs alerts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/monitor-cloudtrail-log-files-with-cloudwatch-logs.html), and [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#events-for-services-not-listed). I would first try the former: I find the CloudWatch Events rule format to be very finicky, and writing the events to logs will let you explore them and perhaps add other notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch Events can send notifications to an Amazon SNS topic when a particular API call is made.

This capability is powered by AWS CloudTrail, but does not need any specific CloudTrail configuration.

See: [Creating a CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on an Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html)